# failure of self-consistency / convergence / structural stability / stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, stability-in-odes

For the DE $$\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2-x,$$ the long term behavior of the Euler approximations with step sizes $h = 0.5, 0.25, 0.125$ with initial condition $(-1,0)$ all tend to $\infty$. However, the long term behavior of the actual solution with the same initial condition actually tends to $-\infty$.

What would I call this failure——failure of self-consistency, failure of convergence, failure of structural stability, or failure of stability?

I had thought it would be failure of structural stability since in structural stability qualitative behavior of the trajectories is unaffected by small perturbations, and here, even tiny deviations using $h$ values resulted in huge effects. However, apparently that's not the case, and I'm not sure which failure this falls under...

Comment: WA gives the following answer $$y(x)=\frac{i x^{3/2} \left(-c_1 J_{-\frac{4}{3}}\left(\frac{2}{3} i x^{3/2}\right)+c_1
   J_{\frac{2}{3}}\left(\frac{2}{3} i x^{3/2}\right)-2 J_{-\frac{2}{3}}\left(\frac{2}{3} i
   x^{3/2}\right)\right)-c_1 J_{-\frac{1}{3}}\left(\frac{2}{3} i x^{3/2}\right)}{2 x
   \left(c_1 J_{-\frac{1}{3}}\left(\frac{2}{3} i
   x^{3/2}\right)+J_{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\frac{2}{3} i x^{3/2}\right)\right)}$$